# No reverse in toggle jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code, shows a div when you click on the button.

But when you, click again, it toggle the div.

I dont need this reverse. I just wanna when you click on the button, it shows the hidden div. and after that, the button doesn't work.

How can I do it?

```js
(function ($) {
      $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#thisclick").click(function () {
         $("#example").slideToggle("slow");
      });
  });
    })(jQuery);
```

```css
h3 {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="thisclick" >Click</button>  
<h3 id="example">Example Div</h3>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `slideDown` to get the effect you want.

`slideDown` is 1 part of `slideToggle`. The second part is `slideUp`

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#thisclick").click(function() {
      $("#example").slideDown("slow");
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
h3 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="thisclick">Click</button>
<h3 id="example">Example Div</h3>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `slideToggle` with `slideDown`.

`slideToggle` combines both `slideDown` and `slideUp` depending on your current state.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "slideToggle", use "slideDown" , that will make it work.